# Connect Google App Engine with on-premises local storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I'm designing a network architecture and I have a doubt about connecting google app engine with on-premises local storage server. Here I'm posting my design and please let me know is this possible or not!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Oh lookey loo! They've added [some networking support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#network_settings) to AppEngine recently!

I think that you're going to have problems with this sort of setup. When you use App Engine you're losing the networking level of control which you get when using Compute Engine or Container Engine. Where you have Cloud Interconnect & VPN, I think you will find that there's no way forward.

Better would be to use Container Engine or Compute and then you can use the Networking capabilities of the platform.